# phonenumber@vtext.com vs. Twilio, Clickatell, etc?

Tags: django, sms, sms-gateway, twilio

I want to let users interact with my Django app via SMS. Twilio's pricing (for a phone number and the volume of texts I'd be processing) is okay, but why would I do this rather than go through carriers' email gateways?

What do API gateways provide that @vtext.com, etc. addresses don't?

Comment: To use the carrier's e-mail gateway, you have to know which carrier your user is on.  To directly text someone you just need their number.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524742/sms-gateway-for-windows-c/3525070#3525070

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What do API gateways provide that @vtext.com, etc. addresses don't?

Guaranteed delivery.

The email to SMS gateways often drop messages, especially if you're sending quite a few messages through them. They might even block you if you exceed a (undocumented, completely arbitrary) rate. Practically, I wouldn't expect more than a 90% success rate sending emails through a cell providers' email gateway.

Beyond that, to use gateways correctly you'll ask your users for their provider, maintain a database of provider gateway addresses (which have been known to change in the past). Remember also that most of the world has number portability; this means you'll need to constantly monitor for delivery failures (from the gateways that even bother to send 'em) and ask users to update their provider.